# Pegar dados em pares em linhas em sequencia

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas

Estou lendo uma planilha `csv` com `pandas` através `pd.read_csv()`.

A planilha contem dados de localização do veículo a cada momento. Por exemplo:

> Local 1: Latitude a, Longitude a
>   Local 2: Latitude b, Longitude b
>   Local 3: Latitude c, Longitude c
>   Local 4: Latitude d, Longitude d
>   Local 5: Latitude e, Longitude e
>   Local 6: Latitude f, Longitude f

Eu preciso mostrar um histórico de distancia realizando o calculo pela API do Google Maps através de:

> Local 1 até 2: xKM
>   Local 2 até 3: yKM
>    etc..

Tentei fazer usando um `apply()` dentro de um `for`, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Pode colocar o código que você tentou usar, e pelo menos um trecho de código em que tenhamos as suas variáveis com os dados, como está fazendo para importar  e usar a api do google, e etc?

Comment: Perceba que sem essas informações, você não está "tirando uma dúvida" - quem fosse reposnder teria não só que fazer o programa pra você, inclusive _refazendo_ as partes que já funcionam, como ainda criar dados de exemplo para poderem fazer qualquer teste.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a [Fórmula de Haversine](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine) para calcular a distancia entre duas coordenadas geográficas das suas amostras:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo (testado) de como resolver o seu problema:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

# Formula de Haversine
def haversine( latA, lonA, latB, lonB ):
    # Raio da Terra em Metros
    r = 6371000

    # Converte coordenadas de graus para radianos
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [ lonA, latA, lonB, latB ] )

    # Formula de Haversine
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    hav = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    d = 2 * r * asin( sqrt(hav) )

    return d


dist = 0;
lat0 = 0;
lon0 = 0;

with open("path.csv") as arq:

    for i, amostra in enumerate(arq):

        lat,lon = amostra.strip('\n').split(',')
        lat, lon = float(lat), float(lon)

        if( i > 0 ):
            dist = haversine( lat, lon, lat0, lon0 );
            print( "[Amostra %d] Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f, Distancia: %f Metros" % (i, lat, lon, dist ) )
        else:
            print( "[Amostra %d] Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f" % (i, lat, lon ) )

        lat0 = lat;
        lon0 = lon;
```

Arquivo CSV de entrada (`path.csv`):

```
-23.55172772,-46.63113769
-23.54896501,-46.64119576
-23.55247579,-46.63805426
-23.54635555,-46.63022746
-23.55371538,-46.63583097
-23.55013902,-46.62514466
-23.54576266,-46.64009231
-23.55461708,-46.64011483
-23.54577566,-46.63642792
-23.54339516,-46.6348212
```

Coordenadas no Mapa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída:

```
[Amostra 0] Latitude: -23.551728, Longitude: -46.631138
[Amostra 1] Latitude: -23.548965, Longitude: -46.641196, Distancia: 1070.287937 Metros
[Amostra 2] Latitude: -23.552476, Longitude: -46.638054, Distancia: 504.915839 Metros
[Amostra 3] Latitude: -23.546356, Longitude: -46.630227, Distancia: 1048.641060 Metros
[Amostra 4] Latitude: -23.553715, Longitude: -46.635831, Distancia: 997.994340 Metros
[Amostra 5] Latitude: -23.550139, Longitude: -46.625145, Distancia: 1159.600298 Metros
[Amostra 6] Latitude: -23.545763, Longitude: -46.640092, Distancia: 1599.514940 Metros
[Amostra 7] Latitude: -23.554617, Longitude: -46.640115, Distancia: 984.569258 Metros
[Amostra 8] Latitude: -23.545776, Longitude: -46.636428, Distancia: 1052.505353 Metros
[Amostra 9] Latitude: -23.543395, Longitude: -46.634821, Distancia: 311.274120 Metros
```